# Admob Reward Video Ad with Adcolony

Tags: java, android, admob, adcolony

I want to display a reward video ad with admob and adcolony.
I followed the official tutorials but I'm not getting it to work.
My App Id and my zone id is configured correctly.

Tutorials:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video
- https://adcolony-www-common.s3.amazonaws.com/pub-adapter/android/AdColonyAdapterIntegrationGuide.pdf

Here is my code:

```
rewardView = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(activity);
...
rewardView.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener()
...

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean( "_noRefresh", true );

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addNetworkExtrasBundle( AdColonyAdapter.class, extras )
    .addNetworkExtrasBundle( AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
    .build();

rewardView.loadAd(config.adMobIdReward, adRequest);
```

The Log output:

```
08-23 12:43:23.494 14581-14581/MYAPPID I/AdColony: ==== Adapter version 1.1.1 ====
08-23 12:43:23.494 14581-14581/MYAPPID I/AdColony: ==== Configuring AdColony 2.3.6 with app/zone ids: ====
08-23 12:43:23.494 14581-14581/MYAPPID I/AdColony: MYADCOLONYAPPID
08-23 12:43:23.494 14581-14581/MYAPPID I/AdColony: MYADCOLONYZONEID
08-23 12:43:23.495 14581-14581/MYAPPID I/AdColony: Adapter initialized, adding V4VC listener
...
08-23 12:49:39.137 14581-14581/MYAPPID I/Ads: Starting ad request.
08-23 12:49:39.138 14581-14581/MYAPPID I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("MYDEVICEID") to get test ads on this device.
08-23 12:49:39.927 14581-14581/MYAPPID W/Ads: : Server parameters: {"gwhirl_share_location":"1","app_id":"MYADCOLONYAPPID","zone_ids":"MYADCOLONYZONEID"}
08-23 12:49:39.937 14581-14581/MYAPPID W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```

I also tried adding my device (using `addTestDevice`) with no success.

**Update**:

AdMob Mediation is still Pending (since 20 days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I missed setting the adcolony ad zone type to `Value Exchange/V4VC`

Comment: where do i add this zone type ?